# Firefox-style Button for Thunderbird 6-7

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

In Windows, you know the nice Firefox button in the top-left corner of the browser that encompasses the entire menu?

Is there a way to get the Thunderbird email client to have the same thing?

Comment: It's been requested: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the answer is that there has been a feature request for it in Mozilla's Bugzilla, as Gareth has metioned in the comments to my question, and that for now, it does not yet exist.

Thanks!